# Rendered viewport shading shows my UV textures but my final render does not show textured objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am using blender cycles render and only started recently. I am trying to make a rubix cube type thing with Mario textured tiles. In the preview mode for rendering under the viewport shading menu looking at the cube is perfectly fine. However, when I attempt to render my cube none of the textured objects show up. I have no idea whats happening and have done some googling but have come up empty, please help.

Please note that the textures are handled using different materials for each face (as seen in the properties panel) and UV mapping to control orientation, the materials in question are controlled using nodes [Texture Coordinate->Image Texture->Diffuse BSDF->Mix Shader->Material Output]

Also there is actually a big solid cube there in the center of the 26 other cubes wich you can see is being rendered (and a little in the 3D view). It has only a basic diffuse BSDF surface and is working perfectly fine in the final render.

[image: Final render in left, Properties on right, 3D view in top and camera perspective render preview on bottom.]

Please help. ;(

Comment: you have at least some "cube" object disabled for rendering, in the outliner. That allows viewport preview but not final rendering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cubes are restricted from rendering, you can set them renderable again by clicking these camera icons in Outliner:

[image]

Comment: Holy cow thank you so much i feel stupid for not noticing this before thank you so much now all my hard work doesn't have to go to waste :D

Comment: Blender is quite complex tool and things like these are easy to overlook so it is absolutely OK you can feel stupid sometimes, I feel with you! :)